# How does the NAT work

Tags: nat

I have a public ip assigned by isp, two phones are connect to wifi router. In both the phones i am seeing news feed on different facebook accounts, so facebook gets packets from only one publuc ip address,how does facebook servers distinguish both the user accounts.. its kind of confusing

Comment: Your question is either about a) how IP differentiates any two streams between the same pair of hosts (ports), b) how streams get different information (urls, cookies), or c) how a NAT router knows where to forward packets (ports, addresses).  You'll get better answers if you clarify a bit.

Answer (score 2):

The connection is identified by a quadruple consisting of

- Source IP address
- Source port
- Destination IP address
- Destination port.

Therefore, the server can still use the ports as a tiebreaker when IP addresses match. Clients choose outgoing ports randomly and your NAT router takes care of the fact that there are no two different connections from inside your network leave with the same combination of public IP address and port.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think facebook distinguish each account based on layer 3 information (IP), they look at this on higher session. each packet belong to their respective session which is tagged at higher level of OSI layer

Comment: Even though the question appears to be OT because it seems to refer to RESIDENTIAL/HOME networking and CONSUMER-grade equipment, I tried to keep my answer on-topic. The OP asked for NAT explicitly and any protocols above L4 in the OSI model are off-topic as to be read at [help].